# Writing Vigenere Cipher in C (Keep Spaces)

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

I am trying to write a Vigenere Cipher (in c) where the spaces are kept. so if I was given a simple message as "hello how are you" the cipher would be in this form "abcde fgh ijk lmn" all I want is to keep the spaces. I have been working on this for a while. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code

```
void CipherText(char* plainText, char* cipherKey)
{
    int keyLength = strlen(cipherKey);
    char cipherText;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(plainText); i++)
    {

        int cipherText = (unsigned char)plainText[i];

        cipherText = ((int)plainText[i]-97+(int)tolower(cipherKey[i])-97)%26 + 'A';

        putchar(cipherText);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: What does not work in this code? How does the current output differ from what you are trying?

Comment: `if (isalpha(cipherText)) { cipherText = … }` — only transform the character if it is alphabetic (but print it regardless).

Answer (score 1):

Test whether the character is alphabetic before trying to transform (encode) it.  Also, don't use numbers for character codes — use `'a'` rather than `97`, for example.  I've removed some casts that are unnecessary. I also used `cipherText` instead of `(int)plainText[i]` as that avoids unwanted sign extension.  I also added some spaces; it's easier to read the code when spaces are used judiciously.

```
void CipherText(char* plainText, char* cipherKey)
{
    int keyLength = strlen(cipherKey);
    char cipherText;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(plainText); i++)
    {
        int cipherText = (unsigned char)plainText[i];
        if (isalpha(cipherText))
            cipherText = (cipherText - 'a' + tolower(cipherKey[i]) - 'a') % 26 + 'A';
        putchar(cipherText);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```